# Ad image alt-text should show company or product name

Tags: feature-request, advertising, alt-text

I've noticed several ads recently that don't clearly offer any information about the product, service, or company they're advertising.  Occasionally the ads are eye-catching and I'd like to know what they're for.  Unfortunately, you guys are tracking these via click-through URLs, so I can't mouse-over to figure out where the ad would take me (and I'm not inclined to click it in that case).

Please add alt-text to the ad-images for the product, service, or company sponsoring the ad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert when it comes to advertising, but I'm nearly certain this is by design.

The idea is that users *should* have to click through to see what it's about because revenue is generated when they click. If the product or service is given away in a tooltip, then people will be less likely to click the ad in the first place, regardless of whether or not they're interested.

Of course, that's balanced out a bit by users such as yourself who will refuse to click the ad without knowing where it goes (I'd be in the same boat if it wasn't for AdBlock), but in general, I don't think people balk at clicking an ad.

That being said, I think this might be a good *test* to run, say for a week, to see how it affects revenue. If it doesn't work favourably, then it can be easily removed.